# Changing line colors in Three.js

Tags: object, colors, three.js, line

In Three.js is there a simple and straightforward way to change the color of an object after its been rendered? And even better, can you change the RGB composition of a color after it has been assigned to a bunch of lines, without going through each line or child specifically?

We have tried several approaches. First, we assigned colors to line segments,

```
lineG.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(xA,zA,yA))
lineG.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(xB,zB,yB))

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) lineG.colors.push(colr) 
newLine = new THREE.Line(lineG, lineMat)
lines.add(newLine)
```

and then we changed the composition of the color as the simulation progressed.

```
blue_one.setRGB(0.0,0.0+a,0.3+a); colr = blue_one
```

where the value of 'a' cycles through 0.15, 0.3 and 0.45 as the simulation progresses. We found that we were able to change the composition of the color before the first render, but not afterwards in the successive renders.

After that we tried assigning different sets of lines to different objects (although they were part of the same storm runoff pattern) and then changing the colors of each one of the objects, but no cigar there either.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried several approaches.
First, we assigned colors to line segments,

```
lineG.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(xA,zA,yA))
lineG.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(xB,zB,yB))

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) lineG.colors.push(colr) 
newLine = new THREE.Line(lineG, lineMat)
lines.add(newLine)
```

and then we changed the composition of the color as
the simulation progressed.

```
blue_one.setRGB(0.0,0.0+a,0.3+a); colr = blue_one
```

where the value of 'a' cycles through 0.15, 0.3 and 0.45
as the simulation progresses. We found that we were able
to change the composition of the color before the first
render, but not afterwards in the successive renders.

After that we tried assigning different sets of lines 
to different objects (although they were part of the 
same storm runoff pattern) and then changing the colors
of each one of the objects, but no cigar there either.